# How do I select an inflation destination?

Tags: inflation, wallets, xlm

How does one set an inflation destination to receive inflation Lumens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some wallets have the ability to input inflation destination (usually in the settings)

> If your app does not offer you an option to set the Inflation
>   destination, you can do it manually by using the **official** Stellar
>   Laboratory. This will work for all wallets, including paper wallet.
>
> Go to https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#?network=public
>
> Click in the tab "Transaction Builder":
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB8pC.png
>
> Paste your Public Key in "Source Account":
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vobpZ.png
>
> Click the blue button "Fetch next sequence number for account starting
>   with...": https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3p8n.png
>
> Scroll down the page to "Operation Type", click the dropdown menu and
>   choose "Set Options": https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7kWz.png
>
> Paste the inflation address
>   in the
>   "Inflation Destination": https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3GH4.png
>
> Scroll down the page and click the blue button "Sign in Transaction
>   Signer": https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUvT.png
>
> You will be redirected to a new page, scroll down and paste your
>   Secret Key in "Add Signer": https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzmAb.png
>
> Scroll down and click the blue button "Submit to Post Transaction
>   endpoint": https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCX9f.png
>
> You will be redirected to a new page, click the blue button "Submit":
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUVq7.png
>
> Done!
>
> Read more about Inflation in official documentation:
>   https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/inflation.html

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/stellartutorials/comments/7mzf7e/how_to_manually_set_inflation_destination/)

Note: If you're using the Stellar Account Viewer and the Nano Ledger S to access and store your Lumens, the steps vary slightly. When you get to the point where you 're redirected to a new page after clicking the "Sign in Transaction Signer", rather than pasting your secret key, you'll use the other option and "Sign with Default BIP Path" before completing the rest of the steps. (thanks [Kißizer24](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/users/232/ki%C3%9Fizer24))

Comment: Note: please verify where you're putting your secret key before you put it anywhere.

Comment: Note: Don't put your secret key anywhere but the official stellar.org.

Comment: Note: If you're using the Stellar Account Viewer and the Nano Ledger S to access and store your Lumens, the steps vary slightly. 

When you get to the point where you're redirected to a new page after clicking the "Sign in Transaction Signer", rather than pasting your secret key, you'll use the other option and "Sign with Default BIP Path" before completing the rest of the steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the Stellar Horizon API to set your inflation destination yourself (without using a wallet app).

You need to create a new `Operation` and [set options your operation to change the inflation destination](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#set-options) that points to the wanted inflation destination.

Here's an example code in JavaScript (from [my own project](https://github.com/jehna/xlmraffle/blob/650f0368cd28e9905e6b9e9aab7df7804c35b777/src/stellarHelpers/stellarHelpers.js#L21-L33)):

```
async function voteFor(target, senderKeys) {
  const account = await server.loadAccount(senderKeys.publicKey())
  const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
    .addOperation(
      StellarSdk.Operation.setOptions({
        inflationDest: target
      })
    )
    .build()

  transaction.sign(senderKeys)
  return await server.submitTransaction(transaction)
}
```

The `inflationDest: target` here sets the inflation destination for your account (="wallet" — the account that holds your funds).

The `senderKeys` is a [Keypair object](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html) holding your own private key, and `target` is the public address of the inflation destination you want to set.

Answer (score 2):

As a complementary to @Rubber Ducky's and @jehna1's excellent answers, I'll add some existing external tutorials which I think are more user friendly.

1. [Set Up Your Lumen Inflation](https://www.lumenauts.com/tutorials/how-to-join-the-inflation-pool) by [Lumenaunts](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/7pu1yz/lumenaut_community_pool/). it's essentially the same as @Rubber Ducky's answer however with some screenshots. This site also provides [a couple of other nice tutorials](https://www.lumenauts.com/tutorials) for beginners.
2. [With Stellar Desktop Client](http://xlmpool.com/sdc-en.html). [Stellar Desktop Client](https://github.com/stellarchat/desktop-client) has been listed on https://www.stellar.org/lumens/wallets/ for relatively a long time and is majorly developed by the [ripplefox.com](https://ripplefox.com/) anchor, it has built-in xlmpool/RippleFox pool support but you can surely customize with your preferred inflation address.
3. [With Ledger Nano S](http://www.xlmnews.com/?p=112). It still utilizes the [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) but specialized for Ledger Nano S.
4. [With Firefly mobile wallet](http://xlmpool.com/firefly-en.html). [Firefly](https://wallet.fchain.io/) is developed by a Chinese Stellar-based company [fchain.io](https://fchain.io/en/) and the repository is hosted on [GitHub/StellarCN](https://github.com/StellarCN/firefly).

EDIT: I know SE does not advocate linking to external pages without self-contained answers, however these tutorials are either specific to clients/wallets, or cannot be rendered well at SE sites.